# Problems with MSDTC - remote transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions, windows-server-2008, msdtc

We're in the process of moving our SQL Server to it's own machine, but I'm having issues getting transactions through MSDTC to work.

Here is the error message ASP.Net is generating for me:

> The transaction manager has disabled
>   its support for remote/network
>   transactions

I have tried googling around for this, but haven't managed to find much other than a guide of how to solve this for Windows 2003.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue on Windows 2008? (Both SqlServer + IIS box are running Win 2k8).

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It can be done from Component Services. Microsoft have jiggled the tool around this from Vista onwards. If Component Services isn't available on your Administrative Tools menu, goto Start>Run and type in '`dcomcnfg`'.

Then you need to navigate the hierarchy as follows: Computers > My Computer > Distributed Transaction Coordinator > Local DTC.

Then right-click on *Local DTC*, select *Properties* ... and then select the *Security* tab. From this tab, you should be able to switch on Network DTC.

You might also need to add an exception for DTC into the Windows Firewall.

More details (included recommended settings, and firewall twiddling) at Microsoft on Technet behind this link... [Enabling DTC Network Acccess (Vista/2008)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753510(WS.10).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I found a good general roundup for [MSDTC issues](http://www.sqlwebpedia.com/content/msdtc-troubleshooting) . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, you go to Component Services>Computers>MyComputer>Properties>MSDTC Tab>Security Configuration Button and then check the proper permissions there.

But that is 2003 as well.

Comment: This doesn't work on 2008 unfortunatly - those checkboxes for the permissions aren't in there.

Comment: This is valid for XP, 2k3 and earlier. For Vista, 2k8 and later, see below.